# Usando Função que não teve a biblioteca incluída em C++

Tags: c++, vector

Eu estava lendo sobre a função `max_element` na documentação do C++ que é uma função que aponta para o maior elemento numa lista, vetor, etc... E lá dizia que essa função pertence a [biblioteca algorithm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm)
então fui testar. O código ficou assim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   vector <int> num = {3, 6, 1, 4};
   cout << "Maior Elemento: " << *max_element(num.begin(), num.end()) << endl;
   
   
   return 0;
}
```

Ele executou do jeito certo, mostrou o maior elemento do vetor que no caso era 6.

Mas eu reparei que tinha esquecido de incluir a biblioteca `algorithm`
que é onde a função `max_element`
pertence.

Mas então porquê não houve erro se eu nem incluí a biblioteca daquela função que estava usando? Algum bug no compilador?

Comment: Nunca assuma que o bug é no compilador (raramente é). Pense assim: o compilador do C++ é usado há décadas por milhares de profissionais para fazer programas altamente complexos. Qual a chance de um programa simples causar um bug que passou despercebido por todos esses profissionais? Não estou dizendo que é impossível, mas é **muito** improvável. O mais provável é o que foi respondido aí embaixo (ou algum outro problema mais simples, ou no programa, ou na forma que vc compilou). Achar que é "bug no compilador" nunca deve ser a primeira opção (nem a segunda, nem a centésima...)

Answer (score 1):

Deve ser uma especificidade da implementação da biblioteca que é usada no seu sistema. É possível que a implementação da biblioteca `vector` que seu compilador tem acesso já inclua a biblioteca `algorithm` e tudo funciona. Outras implementações da mesma biblioteca podem não incluir então o erro ocorrerá e será necessário incluir a biblioteca `algorithm`.

Por exemplo, compilando com o g++ incluído na minha versão Ubuntu dá erro:

```
$ g++ max.cpp 
max.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
max.cpp:7:35: error: ‘max_element’ was not declared in this scope
    cout << "Maior Elemento: " << *max_element(num.begin(), num.end()) << endl;
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
max.cpp:7:35: note: suggested alternative: ‘max_align_t’
    cout << "Maior Elemento: " << *max_element(num.begin(), num.end()) << endl;
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
                                   max_align_t
```

No meu caso, terei que incluir `algorithm`. Para decidir se vai incluir ou não a biblioteca vai depender do caso. Se você tiver controle sobre todas as etapas do processo de geração dos seus binários você pode deixar como está. Se você vai distribuir seu código fonte e não sabe quem ou em qual plataforma será compilado, é melhor incluir.

Se você usar o g++ você consegue ver os headers inclusos em `vector`. Crie um arquivo `temp.c` com apenas:

```
#include <vector>
```

Então, compile com o -M, assim:

```
$ g++ temp.c -M
```

Assim, será impresso na saída padrão todos os headers incluídos na biblioteca `vector`.